# Click on an element and toggle the height and width from another one

Tags: jquery

I want to click on an element in jQuery and then toggle the *height* and *width* of another element.

I know how to toggle when clicked on it, but I want the element to toggle when I click on another element.

Here is my code

```
$('#top').click(function () {
    $("#topbar").toggle(function () {
        $(this).css('height', '400px');
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('height', '100px');
    });
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/2200/

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I improved your question. Please let us know if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
<div id='topbar'>toggle me</div>
<div id="other">Other element</div>

$("#topbar").toggle(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 40
    }, 200);
    $("#other").animate({
        height: 40
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 10
    }, 200);
    $("#other").animate({
        height: 10
    }, 200);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/2201/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#top').toggle(function () {
    $("#topbar").css('height', '400px');
}, function () {
    $("#topbar").css('height', '100px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i forgot to update JSFiddle, this is my real need Example :)

```
$('#top').toggle(function () {
    $("#topbar").css('height', '400px');
}, function () {
    $("#topbar").css('height', '100px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/2200/

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#topbar").toggle(function(){
    $('#topbar2').animate({height:40},200);
},function(){
    $('#topbar2').animate({height:10},200);
});
```

See the fiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fsbyaLwq/)